# Get image from offscreen canvas

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to draw graphics off screen and transfer to Google Sheet.  I've been able to do it on screen with `toDataUrl()`. I have attached a screen shot of JSON `trace` to show the data is getting returned properly.

I found the problem.  trace.size is reversed.  I've corrected the mistake below.  The problem was I was trying to draw off canvas.  Notice that `canvas` is still off screen but within the sidebar HTML Script.

**HTML**

```
<script>
  function sheetsOnChange() {
    var sheet = document.getElementById("sheets").value;
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(
      function (trace) {
        try {
          alert(trace);
          trace = JSON.parse(trace);
          const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
          canvas.width = trace.size[1];
          canvas.height = trace.size[0];
          const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.moveTo(0,0);
          ctx.lineTo(canvas.width,canvas.height);
          ctx.stroke();
          var url = canvas.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);
          google.script.run.receiveDataURL(url);
        }
        catch(err) {
          alert(err);
        }
      }
    ).getTrace(sheet);
  }
</script>
```

**Code.gs**

```
function receiveDataURL(url) {
  try {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
    sh.insertImage(url,1,1);
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

**Trace**

[image]

Comment: What is it about the error message that you don't understand

Comment: If I did this on screen it works.  That is in an html <canvas> element.  Now that I try off screen it doesn't work.

Comment: I found out I can not change the size of the canvas so I am probably drawing outside the canvas.  I'm now trying OffscreenCanvas where I can set any size but it does not have the toDataURL() method so I have to figure out how to transfer the canvas to Google Sheet.  If some one knows how let me know.

Comment: Would you consider providing the code related to the server-side functions you are calling?

Comment: I'm not having any better luck with OffscreenCanvas.   I can not get a blob using `convertToBlob()` and an image is empty using `transferToImageBitmap()`